# Navigation list vanishes when browser gets smaller

Tags: html, css

So I am new to html/css and I'm trying to make my site responsive. So far everything seems to be working okay minus the navigation. When the browser width gets really narrow, it vanishes. Ideally, I would like to have it align directly under the header when the browser gets so narrow. Everything else adjusts fine, although I'm sure I have a few improper techniques at this point. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

HTML:

```
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
         <h1>MY<br/>NAME</h1>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="feature">
                <p>Feature</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article column1">
                <p>Column One</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article column2">
                <p>Column Two</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article column3">
                <p>Column Three</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer Text</p>
        </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
        max-width: 90%;
        margin:  auto;
        font-size: 100%;
         }



    h1 {
        font-family: 'bikoblack';
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 85%;
        color: #2d9471;
        background-color: #1a5642;
        float: left;
        padding: 1em;
        }


    #header {
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: ""; 
        }

    #nav {
        position: relative;
        top: 11em; 
        }

    li {
        display: inline;
        font-family: 'bikoregular';
        color: #2d9471;
        padding: 4em;
        }



    #feature{
        margin: 1%;
        background-color: #1a5642;
        padding: 2em;
        }


    .column1, .column2, .column3 {

        width: 31.3%;
        float: left;
        margin: 1%;
        background-color: #1a5642;
        }

    .column3 {
        margin-right: 0%;}
        }

    #feature, .article {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It ends up hiding behind the feature box when you make the window smaller.

`#nav` in your css has the property `position:relative` which is changing the position of the nav relative to the parent div, in this case `#header`

What are you trying to do with `#nav`? What behavior are you expecting from it when your view window gets smaller?

Comment: The nav is positioned to the right of the header when the page is at full width. I'd just like it to move underneath the header in a block display when the page shrinks to a really narrow view.

Comment: Simply removing the `position:relative` will fix your problem. If you're interested in responsive design, you should really take a look at media queries [link](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)
You can start to get really creative once you start messing around with those. You code with media queries might look something like this
`@media (min-width: 767px){#header h1{width:100%;}}`
which would make the name box full width and push the navigation down when the window is less than 767px

Answer (score 0):

Added Media Query. I hope this is what you had in mind.

```
@media (max-width:480px){
    #nav {
        position: relative;
        top: 0em; 
        width:200px;
        }    
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/09qkcbx1/3/

Note: Play around with the media queries for different sizes to get your elements to display as per your wish on different screens.

Comment: That seems to work better for when the page shrinks but it moves the alignment of the nav to the top of my header when the browser is at full view. What I would like to have it look like is the nav floated to the right of the header and aligned to the bottom when the browser is at full view. And then when the browser gets narrow I would just like the nav to display in a block format under the header. I seem to be able to accomplish one but not both.

Comment: Ok. So in CSS, there exists a concept of `media queries` which take care of positioning your elements depending on the the size of the screen. This is responsive design. A very basic introduction to responsive design is given here: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps. I've added an edit to the answer above. You should also have a look at frameworks like Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ which take care of the basic CSS and layout of your project.